# Why i'm getting exception InvalidDeploymentException when running the program?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can't find where i'm using the Logger. Not in Form1 constructor for sure.
So i can't figure out why it's even getting to this Module at first place and why it's throwing this exception.

This is the Module code:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Module Name  : Logger
 * Description  : A logger
 * Author       : Danny
 * Date         : 10/02/2010
 * Revision     : 1.00
 * --------------------------------------------------------------*/


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
/*
 *  Introduction :
 * 
 *  This module is a logger. any module can use this 
 *  module to log its actions.
 * 
 * 
 * */

        /*----------------------------------------
         *   P R I V A T E    D E F I N I T I O N S 
         * ---------------------------------------*/


namespace DannyGeneral
{
    class Logger
    {
        /*----------------------------------------
         *   P R I V A T E     C O N S T A N T S 
         * ---------------------------------------*/
        static string log_file_name = @"\logger.txt";
        static string full_path_log_file_name;
        static string path_log;
        static Mutex mut;
        /*----------------------------------------
         *   P R I V A T E     V A R I A B L E S 
         * ---------------------------------------*/

        /*---------------------------------
         *   P U B L I C   M E T H O D S 
         * -------------------------------*/

        /*----------------------------------------------------------
         * Function     : Logger
         * Description  : static Constructor
         * Parameters   : none
         * Return       : none
         * --------------------------------------------------------*/
        static Logger()
        {
            mut = new Mutex();
            path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath)+ @"\log";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path_log))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path_log);
            }
            full_path_log_file_name = path_log + log_file_name;
        }

        /*----------------------------------------------------------
         * Function     : Write
         * Description  : writes a string to the log file
         *                This functions will add time and date and
         *                end of line chars to the string written to
         *                the file.
         * Parameters   : string to write to the file.
         * Return       : none
         * --------------------------------------------------------*/
        public static void Write(string str)
        {
            if (mut.WaitOne() == false)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(full_path_log_file_name, true))
                {
                    sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "--" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " ==> " + str);
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        public static void exist()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path_log + log_file_name))
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path_log + log_file_name);
                sw.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"--"+DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()+" ==> "+"First Time The Log File Was Created"+Environment.NewLine);
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        public static void newEmptyLine()
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path_log + log_file_name,true);
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.Close();
        }

        /*---------------------------------
         *   P R I V A T E    M E T H O D S 
         * -------------------------------*/

    }
}
```

The exception is on the line:

```
path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath)+ @"\log";
```

StackTrace: at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment()

And another thing maybe there is a way after running the program and the exception was throw somehow to find what/where in the program was called this Module ?

When i use debug a break point on the line

```
path_log = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath)+ @"\log";
```

And put the mouse on the: LocalUserAppDataPath
I see the path: C:\Users\Chocolade\AppData\Local\Youtube_Manager\Youtube-Manager\1.0.0.0

But why it's going/showing the path with the 1.0.0.0 ? It should be only: C:\Users\Chocolade\AppData\Local\Youtube_Manager\Youtube-Manager

Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath)
```

to

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```